# JPA join entity on the same entity

Tags: join, jpql

I have a question about JPQL. I need to join entity on the same entity. Entity.child_id is mapped as a collection in JPA entity class, i.e. entity have a collection property ("children") which holds every child. Join works fine with this collection (don't know why, by the way), for example:

```
SELECT parent.id, child FROM Entity parent JOIN parent.children child
```

The question is, is there a way to write this query without JOIN, something like this:

```
SELECT parent.id, child FROM Entity parent, Entity child WHERE <condition>
```

I don't know how to construct a condition. "parent.children = child" doesn't work - the left side is collection and the right side is a single entity. Something like "child IN (parent.children)" has to be used, I guess, but I don't know how to do this exactly. I need it because I can't combine general join with another joins in more complicated query.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll answer myself.

1st way:

```
SELECT parent.id, child FROM Entity parent, IN(parent.children) child
```

2nd way:

```
SELECT parent.id, child FROM Entity parent, Entity child WHERE child MEMBER OF parent.children
```

Only the 2nd query is extremely dangerous, it generates very heavy cross-join sql query with IN.
If somebody has a better solution - I'd really apreciate if you share, I haven't solved the whole task yet.